# Word problem optimization derivative

Tags: calculus, optimization

A producer of nuts estimated from past records that if 20 trees are planted per acre, then each tree will have an average of 60 pounds of nuts per year. If, for each additional tree planted per acre, the average yield per tree drops 4 pounds, how many trees should be planted to maximize production per acre? What is the maximum production?

Let $x=$ number of additional trees and $P=$ production of nuts per acre. So the function I'm thinking of for the production is

$$P(x)=(20+x)(60-4x)$$
$$P(x)=1,200-80x+60x-4x^2$$
$$P(x)=1,200-20x-4x^2$$

Then I differentiate it.

$$P'(x)=-20-8x$$

When I try to find critical values, here is my problem. I'm getting a negative one and x represents the trees so it can't be negative.

$$-20-8x=0$$
$$-8x=20$$
$$\frac{-8x}{-8}=\frac{20}{-8}$$
$$x=-2.5$$

So if I'm getting a negative value can't be critical because is not part of the domain. So, I'm wondering if I set wrong the function. Or if the problem has an error.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing wrong. This is telling you to *decrease* the number of trees from $20$ to $17.5$, since you can’t do that you have to take the closest integers: either $17$ or $18$. Both values give the same output: $1224$ nuts every year.

Comment: I have been doing other exercises of this type. I have to use the 2nd derivative criteria. That I have to find the critic value and then find the 2nd derivative and evaluate it using the critical value to show if the function is concave down or up to conclude that there is a max or a min in that critical value. 

Seeing this exercise of the same type of this, the critical value is positive so it makes sense. When I get a negative is not making sense to me. :(

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906463/a-farmer-owns-50-papaya-trees-each-tree-produces-600-papayas-in-a-year-for-eac

Comment: @gi2302 Why do you fear the negative value? You’re assuming that the optimimum number of tress will always be greater than $20$. The parabola is downward facing (concave down) and will have a peak at $x=-2.5$.

Comment: No. I'm not fearing. It is just that is most of these problems are in the context that $x$ is a non-negative value. So yes when I find the second derivative and evaluate it in -2.5 is negative so is concave down and it a has a maximum. But in the other problems, I usually answer with the $x$ and the $y$. So for me, it does not make sense to plant -2.5 trees to have a maximum production of 1,225 nuts per acre. : - /

Comment: @gi2302 Use your brain a little more. You’re planting 17/18 trees, not $-2.5$.

Comment: agh... ok.. I think I get it... The question is how many trees should be planted to maximize production. So it is 20+(-2.5) = 17.5. Right?

I think I was stuck thinking that it was asked how many additional trees should be planted.

Comment: @gi2302 Yes, you finally understand. Planting $-2.5$ additional trees is the same as cutting off $2.5$ trees.

Comment: thanks so much. :)